# rubyでエラーをおこしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rubyで特定の結果の場合にエラーを起こしたいのですが、こういう場合どうしたらよいのでしょうか。

例えば、webapiを叩いて`json`を取得するときに`error`という項目が存在したらエラーを返すというものです。

Comment: エラーというのは何がどのような状態になる(どのような動作をする)事を指しているのか、質問を編集して具体的に書いてください

Answer (score 1):

[Kernel.#raiseとか](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/method/Kernel/m/raise.html)で例外投げるのではダメですか？

Answer (score 0):

raise StandardError, "エラー内容"